# Markdown formatting in Google Keep?

Tags: markdown, google-keep

Is it possible to use [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) formatting in [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/)?

Comment: This would really be a great improvement for Keep.

Comment: @woogy I'm happy to support any feature request. Any idea how we could show the demand for this feature by the community to Google?

Comment: This extension should make it into the Chrome Webstore! https://github.com/sasindumendis/remarkable-googlekeep/issues/1

Comment: Use the *Send feedback* feature from the sidebar in Keep to send ideas for new features.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately, no. There does not appear to be any formatting options available, other than things like lists and note color.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to do this using the Chrome extension [Google Keep PowerUp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-powerup/popfcpchhcihipngccmnfdacakoicolm?hl=en). You just need to label a note as 'markdown' or a custom label which can be specified in the settings.

Comment: Welcome. Please disclose your affiliation to the recommended software.

Comment: @Rubén I am not affiliated to that software. I just found it after some google searches.

Comment: The link appears to be dead, and couldn't find it in the list [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/google%20keep?_category=extensions)

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it might work: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/markdown-for-google-keep/memepciffhlkcckkmkbaccpmmfjjpdfg